# Firebase A/B testing set specific variant for a user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I have A/B testing in my application with two variants.

The thing that I want to do is to set a specific user in a variant by myself(Like with his firebase token)I don't know how to achieve this.

I couldn't find anything in the firebase panel for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set / remove a variant to specific user by its FirebaseToken on Firebase Console.

In your A/B experiment, click `Manage test devices` and determine a variant for a specific token.

Check out this documentation for more details.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config#validate_your_experiment_on_a_test_device